# Convert Multiline textbox value split in another Textbox with comma

Tags: vb.net

I need a little help because I feel a little messy. If we say some Textboxes ... like:

```
Textbox1.Lines(0) = 21,22
Textbox1.Lines(1) = 23,24
Textbox1.Lines(2) = 21,22
Textbox1.Lines(3) = 51,52
Textbox1.Lines(4) = 61,62
```

Ok, so now I want to Display in another textbox: gen: Box1.Text = `21,22,23,24,51,52,61,62`

How? 
I tried something, but it does not work for me. I know maybe it's a simple exercise, but I learn, and I learned, and I like to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ and `String.Join`:

```
Dim allNumbers = From line In Textbox1.Lines
                 From num In line.Split({","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                 Select num.Trim()
Dim orderedAndDistinctNumbers = allNumbers.Distinct().OrderBy(Function(n)n)
Box1.Text = String.Join(",", orderedAndDistinctNumbers)
```

Comment: He does not show me one line: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 and still below the line.

Comment: It shows them the same, each in line, but how do I display the values on the same line? I do not want to be one under the other.

Comment: @PopaIonescu: they are all on same line. You haven't mentioned that the numbers are in multiple lines and that you want them in one.